# Search string in a range (text template) and replace from dynamic rows

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a template which is in range called `rngP1`.

And this contains a text below:

> "This is to confirm that **strTitle** has been enacted on **strDate** for **strCompany**."

Basically, I have a data in another sheet that will be used to replace these 3 strings from my template:

[image]

So what I would like to happen is that in every row data it will search strings **strTitle**, **strDate**, and **strCompany** and replace them according to the data of each row.

I have a code already, however, it doesn't work as I expected:

```
Sub example()
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Set wsMain = Sheets("Main")
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
    Set wsTemplate = Sheets("Template")
    Dim textToReplace As Variant
    Dim array_example()
    Dim Find_Text As Variant
    Dim str As String

    last_row = wsMain.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'Last row of the data set

    ReDim array_example(last_row - 1, 2)

    Find_Text = Array("strTitle", "strDate", "strCompany")
    str = wsTemplate.Range("rngP1").Value
    'Storing values in the array
    For i = 0 To last_row - 1   
        array_example(i, 0) = wsMain.Range("A" & i + 2)
        array_example(i, 1) = wsMain.Range("C" & i + 2)
        array_example(i, 2) = wsMain.Range("D" & i + 2)    
    Next

    For i = LBound(array_example, 1) To UBound(array_example, 1)
        For j = LBound(array_example, 2) To UBound(array_example, 2)
            For a = 0 To UBound(Find_Text)       
                str = Replace(str, Find_Text(a), array_example(i, j))   
            Next a
        Next j

        MsgBox str
    Next i  
End Sub
```

Wrong Output:

[image]

It should be:

> This is to confirm that Title1 has been enacted on 13-October-18 for Company X.

And next one would be the next row which is `title 2`. So on and so fort.

If you have an alternative way to do it, I appreciate it.

Comment: I didn't test it, but I guess you need to get rid of `For a = 0 To UBound(Find_Text)` loop and instead write three lines with replacing.

Comment: Str is defined as a string.  You assign to it once outside of the loops. In the loops you then repeatedly do replaces on str.  As str is a vba variable which is not linked to your worksheet this may be where you have your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:

1. You can push the data range from a worksheet into an array with one line without looping

   ```
   DataArr = wsMain.Range("A2:D" & LastRow).Value
   ```
2. You need only 2 loops for the replacing:

   - one to loop through the data rows
   - one to loop through the variables to replace
3. Your template `str` was not initialized within the loop, but you need a fresh template for every data row.

Note that the array loaded from the range starts counting from `1` but the variables array starts counting from `0`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()
    Dim Template As String
    Template = "This is to confirm that strTitle has been enacted on strDate for strCompany."
    'load your template string from worksheet here!

    Dim Variables As Variant 'variables to be replaced
    Variables = Array("strTitle", "strDate", "strCompany")

    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

    Dim LastRow As Long 'this method is more reliable to find the last used row
    LastRow = wsMain.Cells(wsMain.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim DataArr As Variant 'load the complete data range into an array
    DataArr = wsMain.Range("A2:D" & LastRow).Value

    Dim Output As String

    Dim iRow As Long, iVar As Long
    For iRow = LBound(DataArr, 1) To UBound(DataArr, 1) '1 to LastRow
        Output = Template 'initialize with the template!

        For iVar = LBound(Variables) To UBound(Variables) ' 0 to 2
            Output = Replace(Output, Variables(iVar), DataArr(iRow, iVar + 1))
        Next iVar

        Debug.Print Output
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Peh, I have tried to code above. Also, thanks for explanation.